# jQuery highlight table row except top one

Tags: jquery, html-table, row, highlight

```
$('table tr').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

The following code lets me easily highlight each table row on a mouseover - however, I don't want to highlight the first row.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Thank you all for such fantastic, quick and effective responses.  Appreciated.

Comment: If the first row is a table header, then you should wrap it in a [`<thead>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) tag and use the [`table tbody tr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) selector instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this -

```
$('table tr:not(:first)').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Or you can use `gt`

```
$('table tr:gt(0)')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table tr:gt(0)').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

In case you don't feel like looking it up, the `:gt()` modifier represents `greater than` where the number inside the parans is the zero based index of the element (from the set of elements returned by the selector, in this case `table tr`). In turn, `:lt()` is `less than`, `:eq()` is equals, and `:even` and `:odd` are self-explanatory.